# Ordering nodes in XSL Transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BigData version="2.1" xmlns="bank.xsd">
<InsideData type="plan" name="testBANK" id="10">
<header>
  <log dateTime="2013-07-27T15:52:30"/>
</header>
<object class="BANK"  distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/BANK-1" operation="create"  timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:48:20"/>

<object class="BranchItemPeriod"  distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/BANK-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-1/BranchItemPeriod-1" operation="create"  timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:51:25">
  <p name="Week">0</p>
  <p name="interval">10</p>
</object>

<object class="BranchItemPeriod"  distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/BANK-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-2/BranchItemPeriod-2" operation="update"  timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:51:25">
  <p name="Week">0</p>
  <p name="interval">10</p>
</object>

<object class="Branch" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/BANK-1/Branch-1" operation="create"  timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:48:31"/>

<object class="BranchItem"  distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/BANK-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-1" operation="create"  timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
  <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
  <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
</object>

<object class="BranchItem"  distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/BANK-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-2" operation="update"  timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
  <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
  <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
</object>

<object class="Sleep"  distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Sleep-1" operation="create"  timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
  <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
  <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
</object>
<object class="Dance"  distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Dance-5" operation="create"  timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
  <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
  <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
</object>

</InsideData>
</BigData>
```

Transformation XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:x="bank.xsd" exclude-result-prefixes="x">

<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="x:object[@class = 'BANK' ]">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:object[@class = 'Branch' ]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="distName">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before( @distName,'BANK-1/' ), substring-after( @distName, 'BANK-1/'))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:object[@class = 'BranchItem' ]">
    <xsl:variable name="branchItem" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$branchItem/@operation='update' and not(contains($branchItem/@distName, 'JOBS_CREATED_USING_NE_LOCAL_UI'))">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="operation">delete</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="distName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before( @distName,'BANK-1/' ), substring-after( @distName, 'BANK-1/'))"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="operation">create</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="distName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before( @distName,'BANK-1/' ), substring-after( @distName, 'BANK-1/'))"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="distName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before( @distName,'BANK-1/' ), substring-after( @distName, 'BANK-1/'))"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:object[@class = 'BranchItemPeriod' ]">
    <xsl:variable name="branchPeiod" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$branchPeiod/@operation='update' and not(contains($branchPeiod/@distName, 'JOBS_CREATED_USING_NE_LOCAL_UI'))">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="operation">create</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="distName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before( @distName,'BANK-1/' ), substring-after( @distName, 'BANK-1/'))"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="distName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before( @distName,'BANK-1/' ), substring-after( @distName, 'BANK-1/'))"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BigData xmlns="bank.xsd" version="2.1">
<InsideData type="plan" name="testBANK" id="10">
<header>
  <log dateTime="2013-07-27T15:52:30"/>
</header>
<object class="BranchItemPeriod" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-1/BranchItemPeriod-1" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:51:25">
  <p name="Week">0</p>
  <p name="interval">10</p>
</object>

<object class="BranchItemPeriod" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-2/BranchItemPeriod-2" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:51:25">
  <p name="Week">0</p>
  <p name="interval">10</p>
</object>

<object class="Branch" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:48:31"/>

<object class="BranchItem" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-1" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
  <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
  <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
</object>

<object class="BranchItem" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-2" operation="delete" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
  <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
  <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
</object>
<object class="BranchItem" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-2" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
  <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
  <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
</object>

<object class="Sleep" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Sleep-1" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
  <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
  <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
</object>
<object class="Dance" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Dance-5" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
  <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
  <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
</object>

</InsideData>
</BigData>
```

Desired OUTPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BigData xmlns="bank.xsd" version="2.1">
<InsideData type="plan" name="testBANK" id="10">
    <header>
        <log dateTime="2013-07-27T15:52:30"/>
    </header>

    <object class="Branch" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:48:31"/>

    <object class="BranchItem" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-1" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
        <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
        <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
    </object>

    <object class="BranchItemPeriod" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-1/BranchItemPeriod-1" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:51:25">
        <p name="Week">0</p>
        <p name="interval">10</p>
    </object>

    <object class="BranchItem" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-2" operation="delete" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
        <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
        <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
    </object>

    <object class="BranchItem" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-2" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
        <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
        <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
    </object>

    <object class="BranchItemPeriod" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Branch-1/BranchItem-2/BranchItemPeriod-2" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:51:25">
        <p name="Week">0</p>
        <p name="interval">10</p>
    </object>

    <object class="Sleep" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Sleep-1" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
        <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
        <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
    </object>
    <object class="Dance" distName="CITY-1/ABC-1/Dance-5" operation="create" timeStamp="2013-07-27T15:50:42">
        <p name="openDate">2013-07-27</p>
        <p name="closeDate">2013-07-29</p>
    </object>

</InsideData>
</BigData>
```

I could achieve most of desired output except for few...

1. I want the output to be sorted based on **distName** attribute of object nodes.
2. I want the sort to happen only to certain child nodes with class names as **Branch** , **BranchItem** , **BranchItemPeriod**.
3. Here i try for **update** with **delete** and **create** operation, so i want also to maintain the order of **delete** and **create** too which i do in present transformation logic or else can it so happen that i sort all first based on above criteria and apply the other transformation logic.

Any suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need here is a template that matches the **InsideData** element, where you can then select the child **object** elements in the order you require.

You would first start by outputting the non-"object" elements, assuming these always come before the **object** elements.

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::x:object)]"/>
```

Then you would select the **object** elements with the **class** attribute you desire, sorting in the order you require too:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="x:object[@class='Branch' or @class='BranchItem' or @class='BranchItemPeriod']">
    <xsl:sort select="@distName"/>
 </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Finally, you would output the **object** elements which have the the **class** attributes.

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="x:object[not(@class='Branch' or @class='BranchItem' or @class='BranchItemPeriod')]"/>
```

Try adding this template to your XSLT to see how you get on:

```
  <xsl:template match="x:InsideData">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::x:object)]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="x:object[@class='Branch' or @class='BranchItem' or @class='BranchItemPeriod']">
        <xsl:sort select="@distName"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="x:object[not(@class='Branch' or @class='BranchItem' or @class='BranchItemPeriod')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think the select attribute should be "@distName" rather than "distName".